# Sending Email through Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

Okay, so I have this program which in essence acts as an email client for a company, it constructs the email for them and sends it out.

I've done everything on it, but when going to send the email, they get a `Mailbox Unavailable. Accessed Denied - Invalid HELO Name`

Interestingly though, I use the same username for the network credentials and the from part.

**EDIT:** Update code to what I'm now using... Now getting `Failure sending mail` error.

Here is my `MailConst.cs` class:

```
public class MailConst
{
    
    /*
     */

    public static string Username = "username";
    public static string Password = "password";
    public const string SmtpServer = "smtp.domain.co.uk";

    public static string From = Username + "@domain.co.uk";

}
```

and here is the use of these variables in my main class:

```
public static void SendMail(string recipient, string subject, string body, string[] attachments)
{
        

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential(MailConst.Username, MailConst.Password, MailConst.SmtpServer);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(MailConst.From);

    // setup up the host, increase the timeout to 5 minutes
    smtpClient.Host = MailConst.SmtpServer;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
    smtpClient.Timeout = (60 * 5 * 1000);

    message.From = fromAddress;
    message.Subject = subject + " - " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString().Split(' ')[0];
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = body.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
    message.To.Add(recipient);

    if (attachments != null)
    {
        foreach (string attachment in attachments)
        {
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
        }
    }
        
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Just as a side note. The program works when using my credentials, when going through my own server, just doesn't work when linking it to theirs.

Comment: When they use this program, do they use their own credentials (or do they use your credentials)?

Comment: Also, have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155242/troubleshooting-mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-access-denied-i

Comment: I've been using the program with 2 sets of Hardcoded credentials: theirs and mine... They use the one with theirs. 

Yes I've looked at that answer, and no use as I said in the question, the Username and From are exactly the same, see `MailConst.cs`

Comment: I saw your edit - good catch!  Do you have any more details on the `Failure sending mail`?  Often this means that some setup related to the smtp server is preventing your email from being sent.  Good luck finding it!

Comment: Yeah its working now thanks for your support :)

To use exchange you need to use a Domain to check the credentials, so I added a domain to it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to fix this problem I had to use the optional parameter `Domain` for the `NetworkCredential`

My code now looks like this:

`NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential(MailConst.UserName, MailConst.Password, MailConst.Domain`

Where the `MailConst.Domain` is a string pointing to the Exchange domain.